# How to save json all update data with python

Tags: json, database, python-3.x, api, web.py

## simple.py

```
import json, urllib.request
url = "https://datahead.herokuapp.com/api/employeers/"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

var_json = ?
for i in data:
    print('\n')
    for key, value in i.items():
        print(key,':', value)
```

my json data here such like and you can visit my api link.

```
id : 1
name : Prosenjit Das
log_date : 2019-03-02
log_time : 12:10:12.247257
login : None
logout : None


id : 2
name : Sudipto Rahman
log_date : 2019-03-02
log_time : 12:10:12.247257
login : 11:26:45
logout : 10:49:53
```

Sometimes my data will be update. Now Every historical data i want to save as if i can access those data for calculation.
In this case have to be use any database or without database i can store or save?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

## you can store data
with open('data.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(f,data)


## and can read data from that json file
with open('data.json','r') as f:
    old_data = json.load(f)


## you can compare both data and overwrite data.json if required
```

Comment: Thanks Akhilesh. But I want to calculate into every dict item nad in this case that's not possible to retrieve accurate data. For example: there contains  2 number id login and logout time that how many times 2 id logged out and total value of this date.